# How to run async / non-blocking MySQL queries in Play framework?

Tags: java, mysql, asynchronous, playframework, nonblocking

Just starting out on Play. The documentation talks about how Play can be run asynchronously.

But how to run MySQL queries when running Play asynchronously? Normal MySQL queries are blocking, right? So that wouldn't work.

Node.js has its own non-blocking MySQL clients just for this purpose, but I can't find anything similar for Play.

How do you run MySQL queries within an asynchronous Play application?

Comment: look into this link [Asynchronous jobs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/jobs) in play framework.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I understand how jobs can be non-blocking though. If my MySQL client is blocking, then using it within a job  would still be blocking, no? Or does Play spawn up a new thread every time a new job is created? In that case it kind of defeats the whole purpose of an async framework.

Comment: @Continuation I think you may be confusing "asynchronous framework" with "framework capable of asynchronous operations" in regards to Play! framework? As the linked documentation explains, you can use jobs to perform long-running operations asynchronously from the HTTP request and non-blocking to other incoming HTTP requests.

Comment: You should consider using non-blocking MySQL connector. E.g. https://code.google.com/p/async-mysql-connector/

Answer (score 2):

Play Jobs are executed in a separate thread and release the main http thread. The main http thread is then started where it left off when the Job (wrapped in a Promise object) returns after completing.

So, the main http thread is not held up, and can be made available for handling other incoming http requests.

Answer (score 0):

In general execution of SQL Calls to DB is usually blocking and executed sequentially. Play has great support for Asynchronous execution which improves performance of your app.

**Working code sample for Play 2.0**

```
public static Result slow() {
    Logger.debug("slow started");

    // Start execution
    Promise<DataObject> userObject1 = SlowQuery.getUser(440);
    Promise<DataObject> userObject2 = SlowQuery.getCategory(420);
    // ... here execution is already in progress ...

    // Map to Promise Objects
    Promise<DataObject> res1 = userObject1.map(new Function<DataObject, DataObject>() {
        public DataObject apply(DataObject res) {
            Logger.debug("Got result (userObject1): " + res.toString());
            return res;
        }
    });

    Promise<DataObject> res2 = userObject2.map(new Function<DataObject, DataObject>() {
        public DataObject apply(DataObject res) {
            Logger.debug("Got result (userObject2): " + res.toString());
            return res;
        }
    });

    // here we wait for completion - this blocks
    userObject1.getWrappedPromise().await();
    userObject2.getWrappedPromise().await();

    // the result is available
    Logger.debug(res1.get().toString());
    Logger.debug(res2.get().toString());

    Logger.debug("slow finished");
    return ok("done");
}
```

*feel free to improve using community wiki feature - I am sure some parts can be shortened.*

Comment: But as long as the database client itself is blocking then the Play thread will also be blocked, no? Node.js provides a non-blocking MySQL client so that solves the problem. But I don't think Play offers any non-blocking DB client. Can you explain how does your code turn the DB calls into non-blocking?